# Styling inside an HTML input tag

Tags: html, css

Say I have the following text input element:

```
<input type="text" value="Bruno">
```

Can I make the "B" in the value Bold? So it looks like **B**runo?

I know it is pretty straightforward within `<span>` and `<div>` elements:

```
<span><strong>B</strong>runo</span>
```

But is this possible with an `<input>` element? If so, would the value still remain the same regardless of the styling applied to it?

Comment: You could make the input hidden, and instead display text in a container that looks like your input and style with span and div.

Comment: That would work but what if the field needs to be edited? How can I go about doing that?

Comment: No, you can't, really.

Comment: You can use a javascript library to manage the output into your container. You could use plain js, knockoutjs or some other mvvm library if you're up for that. Just listening to some event would allow you to update the true value in the hidden input.

Comment: you would need to  bind every input event and change the span dinamically

Comment: Thanks for the tips @dward!

Comment: use the `button` element instead

Comment: How do you enter text in a `button` element?

Comment: simple! just do `<button type="button"><b>B</b>runo</button>` performs similar to the `input` as well

Comment: The user should be able to edit and change the value. Thanks though!

Comment: @Bruno Aww, sorry I totally forgot.  Closest thing I can come up [with is this](https://jsfiddle.net/468cs9n8/1/). Basically input values don't support html markup and are just plaintext :(

Comment: That is nifty! I've saved that fiddle, i'm sure I could use it for other projects too :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `<input>` or `<textarea>` element on it's own won't support this type of behavior. You could use an approach that would hide your actual element and use a facade to copy the values from your element and output them as raw HTML into a `<div>` to be displayed :

```
<!-- An element to handle typing your content that calls a function -->
<input id='input' onkeyup='updateOutput(value);' />
<hr />
<!-- Your output element (to display your content) -->
<div id='output'></div>
<script>
  // A function to map your content and output it in your "output" element
  function updateOutput(html){
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;
  }
</script>
```

You can [see an example of this here](http://jsbin.com/ganuni/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

A better alternative might be to use a Javascript-based HTML editor like [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I think I will adapt your method for my needs! I think I will toggle the <span> on click, show the textbox in it's place and then update the <span> using your example and when the input loses focus, i'll hide the input and show the <span> in it's place. Thank you so much Rion, I really appreciate it! :)